# pandas create new column to reflect rank within group based on column

Tags: python, pandas

I have date as follows

| group | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p2382 | 7.55 |
| 1 | p9183 | 3.22 |
| 1 | p1253 | 5.77 |
| 2 | p3382 | 2.11 |
| 2 | p5583 | 1.22 |
| 2 | p1211 | 0.77 |
| 3 | p0482 | 8.55 |
| 3 | p7374 | 8.21 |
| 3 | p2382 | 7.77 |

How do I create a new column 'rank' that outputs the rank of each name in a group based on the score?

The output should be sorted based on rank

| group | name | rank | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p2382 | 1 | 7.55 |
| 1 | p1253 | 2 | 5.77 |
| 1 | p9183 | 3 | 3.22 |
| 2 | p3382 | 1 | 2.11 |
| 2 | p5583 | 2 | 1.22 |
| 2 | p1211 | 3 | 0.77 |
| 3 | p0482 | 1 | 8.55 |
| 3 | p7374 | 2 | 8.21 |
| 3 | p2382 | 3 | 7.77 |

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) with `ascending=False` and `method='first'`:

```
df['rank'] = (
    df.groupby('group')['score']
        .rank(ascending=False, method='first')
        .astype(int)
)
```

`df` (using the first table as input):

```
   group   name  score  rank
0      1  p2382   7.55     1
1      1  p9183   3.22     3
2      1  p1253   5.77     2
3      2  p3382   2.11     1
4      2  p5583   1.22     2
5      2  p1211   0.77     3
6      3  p0482   8.55     1
7      3  p7374   8.21     2
8      3  p2382   7.77     3
```

[`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) can be used to put the new column directly in the correct location:

```
df.insert(
    2, 'rank',
    df.groupby('group')['score']
        .rank(ascending=False, method='first')
        .astype(int)
)
```

`df`:

```
   group   name  rank  score
0      1  p2382     1   7.55
1      1  p9183     3   3.22
2      1  p1253     2   5.77
3      2  p3382     1   2.11
4      2  p5583     2   1.22
5      2  p1211     3   0.77
6      3  p0482     1   8.55
7      3  p7374     2   8.21
8      3  p2382     3   7.77
```

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'name': ['p2382', 'p9183', 'p1253', 'p3382', 'p5583', 'p1211', 'p0482',
             'p7374', 'p2382'],
    'score': [7.55, 3.22, 5.77, 2.11, 1.22, 0.77, 8.55, 8.21, 7.77]
})
```

---

Example with duplicate values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1, 1, 1, 1, ],
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'score': [7, 2, 1, 2]
})

df['rank'] = (
    df.groupby('group')['score']
        .rank(ascending=False, method='first')
        .astype(int)
)
```

`df`:

```
   group name  score  rank
0      1    a      7     1
1      1    b      2     2
2      1    c      1     4
3      1    d      2     3  # Increases even though duplicate
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks good, but I forgot the case if there is a duplicate score within each group, the rank should keep increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `sort_values` with `cumcount`

```
df['rank'] = df.sort_values('score',ascending=False).groupby('group')['score'].cumcount()+1
df
Out[172]: 
   group   name  score  rank
0      1  p2382   7.55     1
1      1  p9183   3.22     3
2      1  p1253   5.77     2
3      2  p3382   2.11     1
4      2  p5583   1.22     2
5      2  p1211   0.77     3
6      3  p0482   8.55     1
7      3  p7374   8.21     2
8      3  p2382   7.77     3
```

Comment: @HenryEcker yw :-) happy coding ~